# Something went wrong after installing vuetify. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'lang'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

After Installing "vuetify". The other component which I have been using happened an error.
I don't know what is going on. the component doesn't be shown in the div.
Is that related to installing "vuetifty"

ERROR

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'lang' of undefined"

found in

---> <VCalendarMonthly>
       <VCalendar>
         <ACalendar> at resources/js/components/ACalendar.vue
           <Root>
```

Code

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(require('v-calendar'));
Vue.component('a-calendar', require('./components/ArticleCalendar.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

```
<script src=" {{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<div id="app">
  <a-calendar url="{{ url }}"></a-calendar>
</div>
```

ACalendar.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      <v-calendar v-on:dayclick="dayclick"></v-calendar>
  </div>
</template>



export default {
    data(){
        return {
          items:[
          ],
          isLoaded : false,
          isLoading : false,
          isError : false,
        }
    },
    props: {
      url : String
    },
}
</script>
```

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
      new VuetifyLoaderPlugin(),
    ],
  });
```

When I removed mix.webpackConfig and VuetifyLoaderPlugin,The calendar component works well.

Comment: Hi looks like you need prop lan in Calendar component